# How to delete css right or bottom on drag

Tags: jquery, css, draggable

i have a draggable div and cannot figure out how to delete the right or bottom css rules when i drag the div.

css

```
#draggablediv
{
    right:25%;/*delete this when i begin to drag*/
    bottom:25%;/*delete this when i begin to drag*/
}
```

Thanks so much.

```
$('#message2').draggable({handle: "#draghand", containment: "#drag_border", scroll:    false },{
    start: function() {
      // alert('started');
      $(this).css({
        "right": " ",
        "bottom": " "});
    }
  });
```

this is the function i use but i does not seem to work... the alert that i put in fires but the properties are not affected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't passing in a value so the code isn't going to change it back for you. The code you need is:

```
$('#message2').draggable({handle: "#draghand", containment: "#drag_border", scroll: false },{
    start: function() {
      // alert('started');
      $('#draggablediv').css({
        "right": "auto",
        "bottom": "auto"});
    }
});
```

This resets the bottom and right back to their default properties.

Alternately, put the `right` and `bottom` styles in a class that you apply to the `div`:

```
.not-dragging
{
    right:25%;/*delete this when i begin to drag*/
    bottom:25%;/*delete this when i begin to drag*/
}
```

...and remove that class when you start dragging:

```
$('#message2').draggable({handle: "#draghand", containment: "#drag_border", scroll: false },{
    start: function() {
      // alert('started');
      $('#draggablediv').removeClass("not-dragging");
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 @Robinhood: Alternately, put a class on the div with those styles in it, and remove the class when you start dragging.

Comment: thank you so much (ps i was not being sarcastic i have been stuck on this for like two hours and could not figure this out) i guess all it needed was a new pair of eyes. lol thanks again though

Comment: @RobinHood: FWIW, didn't come across sarcastic at all. :-)

Comment: @RobinHood: Don't forget to accept Jnatalzia's answer if it answered your question.